# OSPF over IPIP tunnel doesn't work for CSR 1000v in AWS

Tags: cisco, routing, ospf, tunnel

I literally have the following topology shown in the figure below.
I have 4 VPCs, each VPC has 3 subnets (1 for the VM instance and the other 2 for interfaces). Each VPC hosts a `Cisco CSR 1000v` in `subnet-1`.

[image: figure]

I configured `IPIP tunnel` between instances and `interfaces` with the following configurations. It seems everything is okay. 
The `show run` details command is shown below.

R1

```
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       172.0.1.9       YES DHCP   up                    up  
GigabitEthernet2       172.0.1.28      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet3       172.0.1.40      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Tunnel0                10.10.1.1       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Tunnel1                10.10.4.2       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
VirtualPortGroup0      192.168.35.101  YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

The routing protocol

```
Routing Protocol is "ospf 1"
Router ID 172.0.1.40
Number of areas in this router is 1. 1 normal 0 stub 0 nssa
Maximum path: 4
Routing for Networks:
10.10.1.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
10.10.4.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
```

R2

```
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       172.1.1.11      YES DHCP   up                    up
GigabitEthernet2       172.1.1.27      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet3       172.1.1.46      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Tunnel0                10.10.1.2       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Tunnel1                10.10.2.1       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
VirtualPortGroup0      192.168.35.101  YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

The routing protocol

```
Routing Protocol is "ospf 1"
Router ID 172.1.1.46
Number of areas in this router is 1. 1 normal 0 stub 0 nssa
Maximum path: 4
Routing for Networks:
10.10.1.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
10.10.2.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
```

R3

```
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       172.2.1.6       YES DHCP   up                    up      
GigabitEthernet2       172.2.1.28      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet3       172.2.1.46      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Tunnel0                10.10.2.2       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Tunnel1                10.10.3.1       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
VirtualPortGroup0      192.168.35.101  YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

The routing protocol

```
Routing Protocol is "ospf 1"
Router ID 172.2.1.46
Number of areas in this router is 1. 1 normal 0 stub 0 nssa
Maximum path: 4
Routing for Networks:
10.10.2.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
10.10.3.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
```

R4

```
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       172.3.1.8       YES DHCP   up                    up      
GigabitEthernet2       172.3.1.25      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet3       172.3.1.38      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Tunnel0                10.10.3.2       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Tunnel1                10.10.4.1       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
VirtualPortGroup0      192.168.35.101  YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

The routing protocol

```
Routing Protocol is "ospf 1"
Router ID 172.3.1.38
Number of areas in this router is 1. 1 normal 0 stub 0 nssa
Maximum path: 4
Routing for Networks:
10.10.3.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
10.10.4.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
```

The problem I'm facing right now is that, when I do `show ip ospf neighbor` it shows nothing as well as `show ip route ospf` where I got `Gateway of last resort is 172.0.1.1 to network 0.0.0.0`.

All configuration details of the routers are shown below.
R1

```
interface Tunnel0
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.252
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet2
 tunnel mode ipip
 tunnel destination 54.70.35.124
!
interface Tunnel1
 ip address 10.10.4.2 255.255.255.252
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet3
 tunnel mode ipip
 tunnel destination 54.71.64.23
!
interface VirtualPortGroup0
 vrf forwarding GS
 ip address 192.168.35.101 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 ip address 172.0.1.28 255.255.255.240
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet3
 ip address 172.0.1.40 255.255.255.240
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
router ospf 1
 network 10.10.1.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 10.10.4.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
iox
ip nat inside source list GS_NAT_ACL interface GigabitEthernet1 vrf GS overload
ip forward-protocol nd
ip tcp window-size 8192
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.0.1.1
ip route vrf GS 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.0.1.1 global
ip ssh rsa keypair-name ssh-key
ip ssh version 2
ip ssh pubkey-chain
  username ec2-user
   key-hash ssh-rsa ****** ec2-user
ip scp server enable

ip access-list standard GS_NAT_ACL
 permit 192.168.35.0 0.0.0.255

control-plane

line con 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input ssh

app-hosting appid guestshell
 app-vnic gateway1 virtualportgroup 0 guest-interface 0
  guest-ipaddress 192.168.35.102 netmask 255.255.255.0
 app-default-gateway 192.168.35.101 guest-interface 0
 name-server0 8.8.8.8
```

R2

```
interface Tunnel0
 ip address 10.10.1.2 255.255.255.252
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet2
 tunnel mode ipip
 tunnel destination 34.211.24.85
!
interface Tunnel1
 ip address 10.10.2.1 255.255.255.252
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet3
 tunnel mode ipip
 tunnel destination 52.89.60.204
!
interface VirtualPortGroup0
 vrf forwarding GS
 ip address 192.168.35.101 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 ip address 172.1.1.27 255.255.255.240
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet3
 ip address 172.1.1.46 255.255.255.240
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
router ospf 1
 network 10.10.1.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 10.10.2.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
iox
ip nat inside source list GS_NAT_ACL interface GigabitEthernet1 vrf GS overload
ip forward-protocol nd
ip tcp window-size 8192
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.1.1.1
ip route vrf GS 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.1.1.1 global
!
ip ssh rsa keypair-name ssh-key
ip ssh version 2
ip ssh pubkey-chain
  username ec2-user
   key-hash ssh-rsa ****** ec2-user
ip scp server enable
!
ip access-list standard GS_NAT_ACL
 permit 192.168.35.0 0.0.0.255
!

control-plane

!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input ssh

app-hosting appid guestshell
 app-vnic gateway1 virtualportgroup 0 guest-interface 0
  guest-ipaddress 192.168.35.102 netmask 255.255.255.0
 app-default-gateway 192.168.35.101 guest-interface 0
 name-server0 8.8.8.8
end
```

R3

```
interface Tunnel0
 ip address 10.10.2.2 255.255.255.252
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet2
 tunnel mode ipip
 tunnel destination 52.13.239.188
!
interface Tunnel1
 ip address 10.10.3.1 255.255.255.252
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet3
 tunnel mode ipip
 tunnel destination 54.148.168.63
!
interface VirtualPortGroup0
 vrf forwarding GS
 ip address 192.168.35.101 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 ip address 172.2.1.28 255.255.255.240
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet3
 ip address 172.2.1.46 255.255.255.240
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
router ospf 1
 network 10.10.2.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 10.10.3.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
iox
ip nat inside source list GS_NAT_ACL interface GigabitEthernet1 vrf GS overload
ip forward-protocol nd
ip tcp window-size 8192
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.2.1.1
ip route vrf GS 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.2.1.1 global
!
ip ssh rsa keypair-name ssh-key
ip ssh version 2
ip ssh pubkey-chain
  username ec2-user
   key-hash ssh-rsa ******** ec2-user
ip scp server enable
!
ip access-list standard GS_NAT_ACL
 permit 192.168.35.0 0.0.0.255
!

control-plane
!

line con 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input ssh
!

app-hosting appid guestshell
 app-vnic gateway1 virtualportgroup 0 guest-interface 0
  guest-ipaddress 192.168.35.102 netmask 255.255.255.0
 app-default-gateway 192.168.35.101 guest-interface 0
 name-server0 8.8.8.8
end
```

R4

```
interface Tunnel0
 ip address 10.10.3.2 255.255.255.252
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet2
 tunnel mode ipip
 tunnel destination 52.34.186.234
!
interface Tunnel1
 ip address 10.10.4.1 255.255.255.252
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet3
 tunnel mode ipip
 tunnel destination 34.212.97.47
!
interface VirtualPortGroup0
 vrf forwarding GS
 ip address 192.168.35.101 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 ip address 172.3.1.25 255.255.255.240
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet3
 ip address 172.3.1.38 255.255.255.240
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
router ospf 1
 network 10.10.3.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 10.10.4.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
iox
ip nat inside source list GS_NAT_ACL interface GigabitEthernet1 vrf GS overload
ip forward-protocol nd
ip tcp window-size 8192
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.3.1.1
ip route vrf GS 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.3.1.1 global
!
ip ssh rsa keypair-name ssh-key
ip ssh version 2
ip ssh pubkey-chain
  username ec2-user
   key-hash ssh-rsa ****** ec2-user
ip scp server enable
!

ip access-list standard GS_NAT_ACL
 permit 192.168.35.0 0.0.0.255
!
control-plane
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
app-hosting appid guestshell
 app-vnic gateway1 virtualportgroup 0 guest-interface 0
  guest-ipaddress 192.168.35.102 netmask 255.255.255.0
 app-default-gateway 192.168.35.101 guest-interface 0
 name-server0 8.8.8.8
end
```

Note that all the interfaces have been given a public address which is assigned as a destination for each IPIP tunnel configuration.

Comment: Can you ping across the tunnels?

Comment: @RonTrunk I could ping only the router's public address from any instance (`GigabitEthernet1`) of each CSR in the topology but the public addresses of tunnels are not reachable.

Comment: So, I do not see any interfaces with the tunnel destination addresses. Also, none of the tunnel endpoints are on the same network. The tunnel sources must be the public addresses in the router of the tunnel, and the tunnel destinations must be the public addresses of the router on the other end. The tunnel interface addresses must be in the same network on each end of the tunnel because a tunnel is just like a point-to-point connection.

Comment: In addition to @ronmaupin 's comment above, have you considered using VPC-link?  You could eliminate your routers altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure if `tunnel mode ipip` supports link-local multicast, and I'm having some difficulty in finding documentation about it.  Multicast is is needed for protocols like OSPF and EIGRP for the discovery and hello mechanisms (unless explicitely configured for unicast). Most documentation about using OSPF or GRE across tunnels is about GRE or IPsec VTI ('tunnel mode ipsec ipv4').

Comment: @RonMaupin I created 2 interfaces in each router (`g2``g3`) I configured them in different subnets in same network VPC. I associated them with a public address. There's the other interface `g1` which is used to access via ssh to the router itself. The tunnels are in one network (lets between say R1 and R2)`10.10.0.1/30`, so I gave for `R1` its `g2` interface as a source for `tunnel0` and the destination is the public address of the interface `g2` of router R2. I did the same thing for `tunnel0` between R2-R1 by changing the public address of the destination. The result is the `tunnel0` is `up`

Comment: @RonTrunk I'm sorry, I did not get. I'm using different VPC networks and I'd like to make a connection between them using `IPIP tunnel`. As far as I know, I think there is no shuch VPC-link.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi I tried `GRE tunnel` but the tunnel's protocol is always `down`. My problem here is that `OSPF` is configured for the `IPIP tunnels` However, it does not show any neighbor using `sh ip ospf neighbor`.

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia I beg to disagree. From the config shown, OSPF is not configured for the IPIP tunnels exactly. The OSPF config has `network <ip> <wildcard mask>` statements which match the IP addresses as configured on the tunnel interfaces, and therefore considers them as *enabled for OSPF*. OSPF remains agnostic to the the encapsulation and transport mode of the given IP interface. However, unless configured otherwise, OSPF expects an *enabled interface* to support (link local) multicast, so it can send out its hellos. As far as I could research, `mode ipip` tunnels do not support multicast.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi yes, exactly! Let us take CSR1 and CSR2 as an example. The tunnel's network address is `10.10.1.0/30` so for `tunnel0` for CSR1 it should be configured like this `network 10.10.1.1 0.0.0.3 area 0` and for CSR2 part `network 10.10.1.2 0.0.0.3 area 0` which is exactly what I did.

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia remember that the `network` statement in OSPF has nothing to do with the subnet mask or size of the interfaces or prefixes as they are bound to appear in the OSPF topology databases. The `network` statemets with their wildcard masks are only an "access list" or "filter list". Every IP address configured on any interface of an OSPF router will become *enabled for OSPF*, if it matches that access list.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi sorry just edited my comment.

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia (leaving aside that `10.10.1.0 0.0.0.3` is not wrong as such but too large, and that `10.10.1.1 0.0.0.0` would be the correct to-the-point definition) ... Yes, you enabled your tunnel interfaces for OSPF. But OSPF cannot discover neighbors if the enabled interface does not support (link local) multicast. You'll either have to (manually) configure *unicast neighbors* for each tunnel, or use a *tunnel mode that supports multicast*. I can find no documentation confirming or denying that `tunnel mode ipip` supports multicast, but I do know that `tunnel mode gre` does.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi thanks for clarifying! Well I used `tunnel mode GRE` and I got all tunnels' protocol `down`, so I turned to `tunnel mode ipip`

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia as for debugging GRE which seems to remain "down": GRE is *ip protocol 47*, while IPIP is *ip protocol 4*. Do the given (in- and outbound) traffic rules allow for these?

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi I think Security Groups of AWS can allow all traffic and a custom rule can be specified as well as its protocol.

Comment: As Ron Maupin already pointed at: Please review the `tunnel source` statement on each config. The `tunnel source` is the external (or underlying, public facing) interface or ip address for the tunnel. The `tunnel source` interface must have the IP address which matches the `tunnel destination <ip address>` at the other end. The config you show uses 'GigabitEthernet2/3`  as source - I have a hunch that this is not right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86970/discussion-between-khalil-mebarkia-and-marc-netztier-luethi).

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi well, I tried to ) `#tunnel source ?` where I found the source can be given as `ip address` or interface name `Ethernet-Internal Ethernet-Internal interface`.

Comment: See this link for VPC peering: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html